Trying to go into a deep link on clicking a notification, but app opens, but stays on first screen
I have build an android app using flutter and firebase. I have used go_router to set up all the navigation and deep links.  The deep link works correctly when I click on a link (say pasted on whatsapp). However, when I send a notification, I receive the notification, but when I click on it, instead of going to the appropriate page, it just opens the app.
Here are the relevant code pieces, as suggested by codelabs.
Global scope
    // TODO: Add stream controller
final _messageStreamController = BehaviorSubject<RemoteMessage>();
// TODO: Define the background message handler

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');
    print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
    print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');
  }
}

Inside main (before calling run app)
final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Permission granted: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }

  String? token = await messaging.getToken();
  token = await messaging.getToken();

  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Registration Token=$token');
  }

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Handling a foreground message: ${message.messageId}');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.title}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification?.body}');
    }
    _messageStreamController.sink.add(message);
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

Inside my application class
Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("notification: $notification");
      print("message data: ${message.data}");
    }
    if (message.data['type'] == 'newArticle') {
      final channelId = message.data['channelId'];
      final articleId = message.data['articleId'];
      context.go('/RMYCHANNELS/ROneChannel/$channelId}');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupInteractedMessage();
    tokenListener =
        FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((fcmToken) {
      // final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      // if (user != null) {
      //   AppUser.addToken(user.uid, fcmToken);
      // }
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new
      // token is generated.
    });
  }


Is your app running in the background, or terminated?

Is your app terminated or running in the background? If running in the background the onMessageOpenedApp() triggers otherwise you'll get an initial message from getInitialMessage().
If your app running in background just add breakpoint to this line:
message.data['type'] == 'newArticle', and check the remote message.
If your app not running, just show a snackbar with the RemoteMessage data & notification details.
Check the push notification object:
The "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" is important, and must be under data key.
Working example:

If still not working try to create a NotificationChannel:
Use the flutter_local_notifications package to create notification channels.
Example:
Add this code after requestPermission().
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    final AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const 
    AndroidNotificationChannel(
        "my_app_channel", 
        "The channel name of my app",
        importance: Importance.high,
        playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true
    );
    
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
   

And do not forget to update the default notification channel's metadata in your AndroidManifest.xml file:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="my_app_channel" />

I think your own notification channel will solve the problem, because currently the system's default notification channel handling your message, and it's only showing a notification, not forwards your custom data object.

Thank you. Will try that and get back to you shortly.

Sorry. There were two problems with the line context.go('/RMYCHANNELS/ROneChannel/$channelId}');  There is an additional } after $channelId and context was not being recognized.  I fixed the typo and moved the handler code into the first screen after successful login and it is working now. Thanks
